# Adding App-Scoped IDs to an audience

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'me using the facebook php sdk to create an audience (works great) and then add app-scoped ids to that audience (appears to work but isn't working). I can send a hundred app-scoped ids to the sdk and get no errors back, but when I go to the facebook dashboard it says the audience is too small.

Is there a way to add users who've liked a post to an audience via their app-scoped ids? We can already get the list of users who've liked a post (this is the source of the app-scoped ids). Or can you only use app-scoped ids with a custom audience if those users have given permission to Facebook somehow?

(I find it frustrating to not know why a user is rejected from an audience.)

Comment: You said you're adding 'users who liked a post' to an audience? The implication is that these aren't authorised users of the app being used to fetch the user IDs - That's against Facebook's terms and users detected as not being users of your app will be stripped from the audience upon upload. App-scoped IDs work fine in custom audience uploads, provided those users are really users of your app

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I understand. Our facebook page has an App we use for api access, but no one really interacts with it. Is it possible or allowed to segment facebook users that way -- say, an audience targeting users who've posted on our page or liked our posts?

Comment: You can target fans of your page in the normal targeting interfaces but you can't create custom audiences from user IDs you scraped from the API or page, only user IDs of users of one of your apps